# How to extract values from bundle in Android

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk

While sending requests via **Facebook_Android SDK**, I get a bundle in return. Can someone explain what data type it is and how to extract the data in it? Thanks.

`01-28 11:58:07.548: I/Values(16661): Bundle[{to[0]=100005099741441, to[1]=100005089509891, request=134129756751737}]`

**EDIT**
Here, to[i] is a string array. I was able to do it. but I don't think its the right way to do it.

```
for(int i=0;i< size-1;i++){
System.out.println(values.getString("to["+i+"]"));
}
```

where `size` is the size of the Bundle called `value`

Comment: please see my answer - I updated it to contain a loop example over `to` elements without relying on the bundle size.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A `Bundle` is basically a dictionary. Each value in the Bundle is stored under a `key`. You must know the type of value under the key. When you know the type, you access the value associated with the `key` by calling a method relevant for the type of the value (again, you must know the type).

For example if the `key` is `request` and its type is `String` you would call:

```
String value = bundle.getString("request");
```

If the type was `long`, you would call:

```
long value = bundle.getLong("request");
```

To loop over the `to` array provided that the value is of type `String` you can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; bundle.containsKey("to[" + i + "]"); i++) {
    String toElement = bundle.getString("to[" + i + "]");
}
```

which does not rely on the size of the bundle object.

All the keys in a bundle and the type of value for each key should be provided in the Facebook API for Android. If you need further information on the `Bundle` object please look at the [reference here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html).

Answer (score 4):

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getBundle();
bundle.getString("ITEM_NAME");
```